# Adding text and legend to image collection animation in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a GIF image generated using the `ui.Thumbnail()` function

[image]

I wanted to embed the label below, inside the GIF image.

[image]

The GIF is generated using `ui.Thumbnail` and the label is generated using the `ui.Panel`. I Want to combine them together into a single GIF image, so that I could share the GIF link directly.

This is the very first time I am using Google Earth Engine. If this is not the right way to do this, what other way do I have to achieve the same result?

Comment: Note that the URL generated from `getVideoThumbURL` expires after about 2 hours: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization#thumbnail-images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The trick is that all overlays such as text and the gradient bar need to be in the `ee.Image` format. [Gennadii Donchyts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/99557/gennadii-donchyts) has developed modules to achieve this. Once you have the label and the gradient bar as images you can `.blend()` them to each image composing the animation. Here's how:

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c9a527be43ad5a67c6d0dba1d1a3d011)

```
// Fetch a MODIS NDVI collection and select NDVI.
var col = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A2').select('NDVI');

// Define a mask to clip the NDVI data by.
var mask = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('wld_rgn', 'Africa'));

// Define the regional bounds of animation frames.
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
  [[[-18.698368046353494, 38.1446395611524],
    [-18.698368046353494, -36.16300755581617],
    [52.229366328646506, -36.16300755581617],
    [52.229366328646506, 38.1446395611524]]],
  null, false
);

// Add day-of-year (DOY) property to each image.
col = col.map(function(img) {
  var doy = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day', 'year');
  return img.set('doy', doy);
});

// Get a collection of distinct images by 'doy'.
var distinctDOY = col.filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01');

// Define a filter that identifies which images from the complete
// collection match the DOY from the distinct DOY collection.
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'doy', rightField: 'doy'});

// Define a join.
var join = ee.Join.saveAll('doy_matches');

// Apply the join and convert the resulting FeatureCollection to an
// ImageCollection.
var joinCol = ee.ImageCollection(join.apply(distinctDOY, col, filter));

// Apply median reduction among matching DOY collections.
var comp = joinCol.map(function(img) {
  var doyCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    img.get('doy_matches')
  );
  return doyCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
});

// Define RGB visualization parameters.
var visParams = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 9000.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

// Add a color gradient bar with a label.
var style = require('users/gena/packages:style');
var utils = require('users/gena/packages:utils');
var text = require('users/gena/packages:text');

var geometryGradientBar = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-12.907508407699103, -26.822938080181096],
          [-12.907508407699103, -29.915752084430412],
          [10.207725967300876, -29.915752084430412],
          [10.207725967300876, -26.822938080181096]]], null, false);
var min = 0;
var max = 1;
var textProperties = {
  fontSize: 32,
  textColor: 'ffffff',
  outlineColor: '000000',
  outlineWidth: 0,
  outlineOpacity: 0.6
};
var labels = ee.List.sequence(min, max);
var gradientBar = style.GradientBar.draw(geometryGradientBar, {
  min: min, max: max, palette: visParams.palette, labels: labels,
  format: '%.0f', text: textProperties
});

var label = 'NDVI';
var scale = 19567;
var geometryLabel = ee.Geometry.Point([-6.052039657699084, -20.837091553700866]);
var text = text.draw(label, geometryLabel, scale, {fontSize: 32});

// Create RGB visualization images for use as animation frames.
// Blend the gradient bar and label images to the NDVI images.
var rgbVis = comp.map(function(img) {
  return img.visualize(visParams).clip(mask).blend(gradientBar).blend(text);
});

// Define GIF visualization arguments.
var gifParams = {
  'region': region,
  'dimensions': 600,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'framesPerSecond': 10,
  'format': 'gif'
};

// Print the GIF URL to the console.
print(rgbVis.getVideoThumbURL(gifParams));

// Render the GIF animation in the console.
print(ui.Thumbnail(rgbVis, gifParams));
```

You can view the `users/gena/packages:style`, `users/gena/packages:utils`, and `users/gena/packages:text` module code in the Earth Engine Code Editor by visiting this URL:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/gena/packages

...and then finding the `users/gena/packages` repo under the Reader section of the Scripts panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a text to the imagens using python you can use PIL (from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageSequence, ImageDraw)
Read the GIF loop the GIF frames and add the text then save it again.